# : i'd like to find an infinite series of the inverse function g that makes g ( A tan A ) into A

Tags: trigonometry

How to find the mathematical value of $\theta$ for $1 = \theta \tan \theta$

Motivation: For the spiral $r = \theta$ in polar coordinates find the maximum x coordinate in Cartesian coordinates if $\theta \in [0,\pi/2]$

Work done:
$x = r \cos \theta$ and $ r =\theta $ therefore $x = \theta \cos \theta$

I'd like to find an infinite series of the inverse function $g(x)$ that makes $A \tan A$ into $A$

Comment: Let $\theta=\sqrt{\phi}$ and use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

Comment: Awesome thanks for this